# RequestAnimationFrameAPI - Measure load time of single elements - page doesnt load anymore

Tags: javascript, performance-testing, requestanimationframe

I want to measure how many ms it takes for the text to load (depending how I will style it later) and make 10 measurements. I have put it together but with the RequestAnimationCode it seems not to load anymore.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

var stuff = [];
stuff[0] = new Array( "Text1", "Bla1Bla1Bla1" );
stuff[1] = new Array( "Text2", "Bla2Bla2Bla2Bla2Bla2Bla2Bla2Bla2Bla2Bla2" );
stuff[2] = new Array( "Text3", "Bla3Bla3Bla3Bla3Bla3Bla3Bla3Bla3Bla3Bla3Bla3Bla3Bla3Bla3Bla3Bla3" );

var lastTime = 0;
var count = 10; 
var nprint = 50;
var t0 = 0;
var t1 = 0;

//----------------------Start Window loading event---------------------------

$(window).load(function () {

//print links once
$.each(stuff, function(index, out) {
$( "#text" ).append( "<p id='" + out[0] + "'>" + out[0] + " - " + out[1] + "</p>" );
});

//-----------------AnimationFrameMeasure


//loading text 0 50 times
for ( var i = 0; i < nprint; i++ ) {
$( "#testbox" ).append( "<p id='" + stuff[0][0] + "'>" + stuff[0][0] + " - " + stuff[0][1] + "</p>" );
}

function loop(t) { 
var diff = lastTime - t; 
lastTime = t;
t0 = window.performance.now();

//loading text 50 times
for ( var i = 0; i < nprint; i++ ) {
$( "#testbox" ).append( "<p id='" + stuff[0][0] + "'>" + stuff[0][0] + " - " + stuff[0][1] + "</p>" );
}

// push time
t1 = window.performance.now();
    stuff[0].push(t1-t0);

if (count >= 0) {
requestAnimationFrame(loop); 
}

count = count - 1;

} 

requestAnimationFrame(loop); 


//-------------------------print results-----------------------
alert(stuff);

$.each(stuff, function(index, link) {
$.each(link, function(data, value) {

$( "#resultbox" ).append(" | " + value);

});
$( "#resultbox" ).append("<br />"); 
});


//--------------------------End Window loading even ------------

});
</script>


<body>
<h2>Text Overview</h2>
<div id="text"></div>

<h2>Result Box</h2>
<div id="resultbox"></div>

<h2>TestBox</h2>
<div id="testbox"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere at //-----------------AnimationFrameMeasure. DOes someone see the error? Its probably minor, I am blind

Comment: The `count` variable is never updated, thus `count >= 0` is always true and your loop never stops.

Comment: By the way, have a look at `window.performance.now()`, which is specifically made to measure performance.

Comment: window.performance.now() is not supported by Safari

Comment: Here is a polyfill : https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5438650.

Comment: interesting, what is a polyfill? sorry i am not that experienced yet

Comment: Ah, so that fixes the performance.now() problem on Safari?

Answer (score 2):

1. You're missing the `</body>` tag
2. Line 37: `loop(t)` - you probably intended to write `function
   loop(t)`

As a side-note, once these changes are made it just seems to loop infinitely, printing on and on and on.

Get more familiar with your browser's debugger. It would most likely have given you enough information to spot #2, since it complains about an unexpected `{` on line 38.

Comment: ah I had a problem with encoding, I pasted something and it was not UTF-8 . I fixed the issues mentioned. However, the measurement is not shown in the array now...

Comment: stuff["first"].push(diff); does not work inside, but only outside the loop. any idea why?

Comment: I did wonder about the encoding when a `-` character was displayed as a question-mark in a white box, i.e an unmapped character. Um, as for why the push isn't working - nope, I don't jQuery, sorry. It makes the code you type shorter but in my opinion, makes it less readable (I'm originally an asm programmer - i.e do everything yourself) Best of luck! :)

Comment: I find it useful because of the selectors. I can select any ID or Name without any workarounds. The push problem is driving me crazy, I see no reason why it should NOT work inside the loop

Comment: Beautiful! Chrome's debugger will almost certainly tell you why it wont work. Have a look if you haven't already. (hit f12)

Comment: No the debugger doesnt show anything. And it only works, if I run an alert before printing the arrays, and only in Firefox. I am completely lost! I have upgraded the code

Comment: I just tried your code, it did give me an error - two in fact. The first one was `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. The second, `GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js ` failed - look at the path. You should add `http:` to the script src It worked if I ran from localhost but not if I just double-clicked the file, or chose "Launch in Chrome" from Notepad++. So, it seems firefox is handling the url differently. Also, the JS may be trying to run before the jquery lib has loaded - the alert gives it time to load.